# Pimpl idiom implementation depending on a template function

Tags: c++, templates, pimpl-idiom, template-function

Please consider the code below.

The template parameter is a handler class that must provide the function `bar()`.

I'm using the Pimpl idiom to hide the implementation details of `Foo`. Prior to having a template parameter the constructor definition was in `foo.cpp` and all was good.

```
///////////    
// foo.h
///////////    

class Foo
{
public:
    template <class Handler>
    Foo(Handler& handler);

    void someFunction();

private:
    /** Private implementation details. */
    struct Impl;
    const std::unique_ptr<Impl> m_impl;
};

template <class Handler>
Foo::Foo(Handler& handler) : m_impl{new Impl{handler}}
{
}

///////////    
// foo.cpp
///////////    

#include "foo.h"

/** Encapsulates the private implementation details of Foo. */
struct Foo::Impl
{
public:
    Impl(Handler& handler) : m_handler(handler)
    {
    }

    void someOtherFunction()
    {
        m_handler->bar();
    }

private:
    Handler& m_handler;

    friend class Foo;
};

void Foo::someFunction()
{
    m_impl->someOtherFunction();
}
```

Once I introduced the template parameter I had to put the constructor in `foo.h`, which causes the following compiler error:

`Allocation of incomplete type 'Foo::Impl'`.

I understand the reason why I get the error but I can't think of a way around it and still use the Pimpl idiom.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Whenever you create a new instance of the object, you also need to include its full definition. I don't think there's any way around, other than making Handler a base class and using polymorphism.

Comment: Where is the definition of the type referred to by `Foo::Impl::m_handler`?

Comment: @Oktalist That will be somewhere else. What are you getting at?

Comment: The constructor of `Foo` passes its argument to the constructor of `Impl`. The constructor of `Impl` is not a template. How does that work? A precise discussion is difficult when the token `Handler` has two different meanings.

Comment: Or, in short, please provide code that produces your error, and only your error.  And make it not suck: a template type called `Handler` and another type called `Handler`?  Why not just take `Handler` as a non-template type?  If your goal is to hide the implementation of `Handler`, why are users expected to know the types that can be used to construct it (!?).  If not, why not expose it?

Comment: @Oktalist I see. My example is incorrect. The constructor of `Impl` must also be a template. It is the same type as what is passed to `Foo`.

Comment: Yeah, templates need to be defined in the header, so of course you would not be able to define `Impl` in the `.cpp` file if it contains a template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve this with or without virtual functions. The first option is somewhat easier: Use virtual functions, either for Handler

```
class HandlerBase { .... virtual void bar() = 0; ... };
class Foo { ... std::unique_ptr<HandlerBase> handler; ... };
```

or for Impl

```
class ImplBase { ... virtual void someFunction() = 0; }
class Foo { ... std::unique_ptr<ImplBase> m_impl; ... }
template<typename Handler> class Impl : public ImplBase { ... Handler& m_handler; ...};
```

I think these are relatively straightforward to implement. You can see that when using HandlerBase you don't even need the pimpl idiom.

The other alternative is to use the [The Impossibly Fast C++ Delegates](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11015/The-Impossibly-Fast-C-Delegates) method:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    template <class Handler>
    explicit Foo(Handler& handler)
            : handler(&handler) {
        someFunctionInstance = someFunctionTemplate<Handler>;
    }

    void someFunction() {
        someFunctionInstance(handler);
    }

private:
    typedef void (*SomeFunctionType)(void* handler);

    void* handler;
    SomeFunctionType someFunctionInstance;

    template<typename Handler>
    static void someFunctionTemplate(void* handler) {
        static_cast<Handler*>(handler)->bar();
    }
};
```

The type of Foo remains independent of Handler. The assignment in the constructor creates a custom instance of the someFunctionTemplate which is able to call the actual Handler type. SomeFunctionInstance is a result of a template instantiation on Handler but since it's a static function its type is also independent of Handler.

However this solution is tricky and does contain a reinterpret_cast, it is still fully type-safe.

Comment: Why use `reinterpret_cast` when `static_cast` would work just as well?

Comment: Thanks @tamas.kenez. I was over-complicating things. I've implemented a solution using virtual functions.

Answer (score 2):

In general terms, you need some kind of *type erasure*. In practice, this means a function pointer or a virtual function (which is just a higher level abstraction implemented using a function pointer), as in the three solutions offered by @tamas.kenez.

`std::function` provides type erasure, typically implemented using a virtual function. Here is a alternate take on the problem using `std::function`:

```
////////////
// foo.h

class Foo
{
public:
    template <class Handler>
    Foo(Handler& handler) : Foo{ tag{},
                                 [&handler](){handler.bar();} }
    {}

    // ...

private:
    /** Private implementation details. */
    struct Impl;
    const std::unique_ptr<Impl> m_impl;

    struct tag {};
    Foo(tag, std::function<void()> bar);
};

////////////
// foo.cpp

struct Foo::Impl
{
    Impl(std::function<void()> bar) : m_bar{bar}
    {}

    std::function<void()> m_bar;

    // ...
};

Foo::Foo(Foo::tag, std::function<void()> bar) : m_impl{new Impl{bar}}
{}
```

I've used a tag type to disambiguate constructor overloads.

The lambda, which captures a reference to `handler`, is stored in the `std::function` so that the initialization of `m_impl` can be factored out of the template.

Comment: You could leave out the whole pimpl thing, couldn't you? Otherwise I like this better.

Comment: @tamas.kenez Of course you could, but that would just be ignoring the question.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Oktalist. I was over-complicating things. I've implemented a solution using virtual function