# How can I offload dependency injected template class providing templated functions to pimpl class

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, function-templates, pimpl-idiom

I have an application class that can take in a dependent class as a template argument to the constructor. This dependent class is required to provide certain templated functions that the application class can call. I would like to offload this dependent class object to a pimpl class so the application class is not a template class and thus header-only.

Here is a rough idea of what I mean.

```
///////////
// impl.h
///////////

template<typename Helper>
struct Impl
{
public:
    Impl(Helper& helper) : helper_(helper)
    {
    }

    template <typename T>
    void someHelperFn1(T t)
    {
        helper_->fn1(t);
    }
 
    template <typename U>
    SomeOtherClass<U> someHelperFn2()
    {
        return helper_->fn2();
    }


private:
    Helper& helper_;
};

///////////
// app.h
///////////

#include "impl.h"

class App
{
public:
  template<typename Helper>
  App(Helper &h) :impl_(new Impl) {}

  template <typename T>
  void someHelperFn1(T t)
  {
     impl_->someHelperFn1(t);
  }
 
  template <typename U>
  SomeOtherClass<U> someHelperFn2()
  {
     return impl_->someHelperFn2();
  }

  void someAppFn();

private;
  std::unique_ptr<Impl> impl_;
};

///////////
// app.cpp
///////////

void App::someAppFn()
{
  // some useful code
}
```

I realize the above code doesn't compile since Impl is really a template class and so App would also be a template class too. That is what I would like to avoid so that App is not a header-only class. I found something [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29103193/pimpl-idiom-implementation-depending-on-a-template-function) except the functions that I want to call from the helper dependency are template functions and they are not in this case. It seemed pretty close otherwise to what I wanted to do.

Any ideas on how I can avoid making App a template class?

I tried making the helper class use a common base class but that is not really possible with the template functions.

Also, note that I am limited to C++ 17 for the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make sure the public header file (the one with the class that has the pimpl pointer) doesn't expose the header file only class template of the implementation. Use an interface for that like this.
I did not dependency inject the implementation because that should not be needed.

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

// public header file

// for pimpl pattern I often use an interface
// (also useful for unit testing later)
class PublicItf
{
public:
    virtual void do_something() = 0;
    virtual ~PublicItf() = default;

protected:
    PublicItf() = default;
};

// the public class implements this interface
// and the pimpl pointer points to the same interface
// added advantage you will have compile time checking that
// the impl class will all the methods too.
class PublicClass final : 
    public PublicItf
{
public:
    PublicClass();
    virtual ~PublicClass() = default;
    void do_something() override;

private:
    std::unique_ptr<PublicItf> m_pimpl; // the interface decouples from the template implementation (header file only) 
};

// private header file
// this can now be a template
template<typename type_t>
class ImplClass final :
    public PublicItf
{
public:
    void do_something() override
    {
        m_value++;
        std::cout << m_value << "\n";
    }



private:
    type_t m_value{};
};

// C++ file for Public class
// inlcude public header and impl header (template)

PublicClass::PublicClass() :
    m_pimpl{ std::make_unique<ImplClass<int>>() }
{
};

void PublicClass::do_something()
{
    m_pimpl->do_something();
}

// main C++ file

int main()
{
    PublicClass obj;
    obj.do_something();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Two comments:  
1. I need to dependency inject a Helper class since the user of my public class might have a different implementation of the helper functions. This approach doesn't show that.
2. The do_something() method in my case is a template function so can't really use virtual dispatch with a base class interface.

Comment: Fair enough, those details where not clear to me yet. If you cant use virtual dispatch you might consider not injecting an interface but actual functions (lambdas). So everything can be resolved at compile time.

Comment: Yes, that is a possibility but since the Helper class might supply quite a few functions, it's not desirable to inject a whole set of functions in the constructor. It doesn't scale well either. Every time I need to add a function, the client constructor needs to change which is not good since since there are several different clients.